# Changing character font style in dramatist

Tags: fonts, bold, dramatist

Im using dramatist package for writhing a play but the character name font style in this package and dialogue statements font style are same. whereas i prefer the speaker name font style was bold! I search in dramatist.sty file to find code which indicates font style of character but not found. Is there any way to change it? thanks a lot..

Comment: Since most of us are not familiar with `dramatist`, would you please add a small sample document so we can play with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it would be greatly appreciated to see your attempts in form of a MWE, here is a solution.

You have to define the `\speaksfont`-definition.  See my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

%% This will print the name of the speaking actor in boldface
\renewcommand{\speaksfont}{\bfseries}

%% Define some actors
\Character[Son of the house Montague]{Romeo}{romeo}
\Character[Duaghter of the house Capulet]{Julia}{julia}

\begin{document}
\begin{drama}
  \juliaspeaks O Romeo, Romeo, wherefore art thou Romeo?\\
  \romeospeaks Have not saints lips, and holy palmers too?
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

An overview of all the fonts and other settings can be found in the [dramatist documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dramatist/dramatist.pdf), chapter `3.7 Configuration settings`.